# tweak bash autocompletion

Tags: bash, debian, autocomplete, xournal

I am busy with a task from the terminal which is that laborious that it would be of value to tweak something with bash autocomplete.

So a standard Debian package is [xournal](https://packages.debian.org/de/buster/xournal) which I don't have installed (anymore)

What I *do* have installed is [xournal++](https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp) which is launched with 'xournalpp'

The terminal does not realise that and tab does not complete all the way.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: There's no "realize".  If it's on the path, re-hash the shell, or open a new shell prompt.

Comment: What do you mean "re-hash the shell"? I am always opening new terminals so don't that's it.

Comment: Are you perhaps encountering this [issue](https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp/issues/1752) ?

Comment: Yes! Thanks, that did it... Not sure what a thumbnailer is but it fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the behaviour is not of the terminal application as such, but of the shell running within it and more precisely of the line editing library the shell is using (likely libreadline or libedit).

At least for [GNU Readline](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) the default behaviour is **not** to display multiple options when the completion is ambiguous. You'll either need to hit the key that causes completion twice, or add

```
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
```

to your `~/.inputrc` which is read by libreadline at initialisation (it can also be re-read at runtime, by default it is assignet to <kbd>Ctrl+x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+r</kbd>).

Answer (score 1):

Using the link in the comments from @steeldriver

I did this and it was fixed:

```
$ which xournal-thumbnailer 
/usr/bin/xournal-thumbnailer
$ sudo mv /usr/bin/xournal-thumbnailer /usr/bin/xournalpp-thumbnailer
```